# How to align contents of a slice in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is it possible to align the content inside a slice? How?

Answer (score 2):

No — and yes.

A `slice` isn't essentially a grouping element, so you can't select a slice and tell it to align its contents. Consider slices as a grid (or as a wireframe) on top of your design, that doesn't know anything what's underneath. A slice could e.g. *slice* a text element so that its bound could go straight *through a character* if you want it to go — the slice doesn't care.

However, you could `group` your layers so that each `group` holds the contents of a slice. Unfortunately, there's no automated process for this out–of–the–box.

Grouping by slices may not be straightforward if you already have implemented a grouping scheme for your design, but if you really need alignment per slice basis, you might want to reconsider your scheme. An alternative to grouping could be converting the layers as a `smart object` and then aligning its contents.